# How to write a spark dataframe tab delimited as a text file using java

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Spark `Dataset<Row>` with lot of columns that have to be written to a text file with a tab delimiter. With csv its easy to specify that option, but how to handle this for a text file when using Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Option 1 :***

```
    yourDf
    .coalesce(1) // if you want to save as single file
    .write
    .option("sep", "\t")
    .option("encoding", "UTF-8")
    .csv("outputpath")
```

same as writing csv but here tab delimeter you need to use.

Yes its csv as you mentioned in the comment, if you want to rename the file you can do the below..

```
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem;
FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration);
fs.rename(new Path("outputpath"), new Path(outputpath.txt))
```

**Note :** 
1) you can use fs.globStatus if you have multiple file under your outputpath inthis case `coalesce(1)` will make single csv, hence not needed.
2) if you are using s3 instead of hdfs you may need to set below before attempting to rename...

```
spark.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.impl", "org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3native.NativeS3FileSystem")
```

### ***Option 2 :***

Other option (if you don't want use csv api) could be like below

```
 yourDf.rdd
.coalesce(1)
.map(x => x.mkString("\t"))
.saveAsTextFile("yourfile.txt")
```

---

Comment: That ends up with a .csv extension though that should not be an issue, client seems to be asking for  .txt extension if possible.

Comment: I gave another option pls check that.